# What's about the Frullani extension for infinite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, examples-counterexamples

I was thinking about the extension of Frullani that explains Jameson in the notes [*The Frullani integrals*, (lectures notes from Lancaster University).](http://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/~jameson/frullani.pdf) I am saying *FRU2* in page 3.

I tried write speculative examples of this extension in the infnite case. I am saying when one take series instead of finite sums. But I don't know if the *LHS* of the identity  in my examples make sense. For example, if I take weights as $m_n=\frac{\mu(n)}{n}$ for each $a_n=n\geq 1$ an integer, where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function, then I can write a *RHS* that converges with $f(x)=e^{-x}$ , but my *LHS* is

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}e^{-nx}}{x}dx.$$

> **Question 1.** Can you convice to me that this integral doesn't make sense? Or is it convergent? I try do reasonings with the exponential integral, but I don't know what say.

I would like to see some example, if make sense of an example of *FRU2* but in the case infinite.

> **Question.** Does make sense the same theorem *FRU2*, that is the extension of Frullani explained in the lecture notes, in the case which the series are infinite? If you know that it is a theorem (for suitable hypothesis), please refers where we can find the literature, and if it's possible create and provide us a simple example. If isn't possible, that is such theorem isn't feasible  explain us why. **Many thanks and good nights.**

Comment: All users for this BOUNTY @user1952009 added (if I understand the claim) that the integral in Question 1 does converge and this issue of convergence is equivalent to the Prime Number Theorem. Thus I am waiting an answer for Question 2, but it is welcome if you want add details to get the convergence of the integral in Question 1. Many thanks all users, for patience and attention.

Comment: What don't you understand with it is not of your level ? It is impossible to explain this to someone who doesn't know the traditional proof of the prime number theorem

Comment: Then I am sorry @user1952009 As was said only is required what about the combination of Frullani and infnite series: an extension of Frullani  involving infnite series. I am saying that if it has mathematical sense, I am waiting an explanation. Merci.

Comment: Did you work on this http://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/~jameson/frullani.pdf and this https://duckduckgo.com/?q=inversion+serie+integrale ???

Comment: @user1952009 one more time I am saying I am sorry, but in Jameson's lecture notes there is no an answer of my Question, and I don't find it in your second reference. Note that I am asking the extension of *FRU2*, but now for $n=\infty$. Many thanks.

Comment: ça sert à quoi de poser de nouvelles questions sur Frullani si tu n'as pas compris la base ?

Comment: All users I've accepted the answer because provide me the answer of Question 1 and thus an example of my interpretation of Question 2. If in next future some user want to add more remarks/references about the infinite extension of Frullani theorem, is welcome. Many thanks one more time to @JackD'Aurizio

Comment: @user1952009 many thanks for your remarks to the answer, I try study it and understand. On the other hand feel free to add mathematical remarks in any of my posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may start noticing that $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}=0$ - this is essentially equivalent to the prime number theorem, and allows us to consider the better-behaved series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\mu(n)}{nx}\left(e^{-nx}-e^{-x}\right)$. For any $s>1$ we have $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}=\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$ and the $\zeta$ function has a simple pole at $s=1$ with residue $1$.
 By [Frullani's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html)
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-nx}-e^{-x}}{x}\,dx = -\log(n) \tag{1}$$
hence by applying the dominated convergence theorem with extreme caution we have:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\cdot\frac{e^{-nx}-e^{-x}}{x}\,dx =-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\mu(n)\log(n)}{n}.\tag{2}$$
On the other hand, for any $s>1$
$$ \frac{d}{ds}\left(\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}\right) = -\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\mu(n)\log(n)}{n^s} = -\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)^2}=-\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}\cdot\frac{d}{ds}\left(\log\zeta(s)\right)\tag{3}$$
and:
$$ \lim_{s\to 1^+}-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)^2} =\lim_{s\to 1^+}-\frac{(s-1)^2 \zeta'(s)}{(s-1)^2\zeta^2(s)}=-\frac{-1}{1}=\color{red}{1}\tag{4}$$
by the Laurent expansion of $\zeta(s)$ and $\zeta'(s)$ in a right neighbourhood of $s=1$.
So $\color{red}{1}$ is the only reasonable value for the original integral. However, there are a lot of details to be dealt with care: for starters, that the original integral and the RHS of $(2)$ are convergent, but also that we are allowed to use $(3)$ to compute $(2)$ by considering $\lim_{s\to 1^+}-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)^2}$.

Comment: It is a perfect explanation. Many thanks now we can study this exercise. Many thanks for generosity of your explanations to you and user1952009 in this site.

Comment: For showing that $\int_0^1\frac{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}e^{-nx}}{x}dx$ converges I would look at $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}e^{-nx} = \int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty} \frac{\Gamma(s)}{\zeta(s+1)}x^{-s}ds$ and shift the contour as usual

Comment: @user1952009: that is fine, but for technical reasons it is best to consider $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}(e^{-nx}-e^{-x})$ before shifting the integration contour in order to apply the inverse Laplace or Mellin transform.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n} = 0$ and $|a_n| \le 1$ implies that $\int_0^1\frac{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n}(e^{-nx}-e^{-x})}{x}dx=\int_0^1\frac{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n}e^{-nx}}{x}dx$ converges. that's what you meant ?

Comment: @user1952009: exactly.

Comment: I'd say you should add this to your answer

Comment: @user1952009: agreed and updated.

Comment: Jack D'Aurizio many thanks one more time for your answer. I wrote this for you, is not required a response, is as a present for you,  good week.  Let $M(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\mu(n)$ the Mertens function, and we denote with $ \left\{ x \right\} =\text{frac}(x)$ the fractional part function, then $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty M(n) \left( -\frac{1}{4}+\int_0^1 \left\{ nx \right\}   \left\{ (n+1)x \right\}dx \right) =0.$$